# Issue in Creating Angular 2 Project through CLI

Tags: angular, github, angular-cli

I am getting following error message when run `npm install -g angular/cli` command in Visual Studio code.

> 14 error Error while executing: 14 error C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t
>   ssh://git@github.com/angular/cli.git 14 error 14 error Host key
>   verification failed. 14 error fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository. 14 error 14 error Please make sure you have the correct
>   access rights 14 error and the repository exists. 14 error 14 error
>   exited with error code: 128 15 verbose exit [ 1, true ]##

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

:)

Comment: Ok.I tried.Now i am getting following error mesaage. error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...emp":"0.8.3","through'

Comment: what version of node are you running on? `node -v`

Comment: E:\Project>node -v
v8.11.2

Comment: hmm try clearing the cache first

`npm cache clean --force` and then download it again

Comment: Getting Error like Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."^1.0.14","@angular-c'

Comment: did you close the terminal and open it again after you clear cache? this sounds like an node issue. maybe check your npm version too? `npm -v`